# How to install pycaw

Tags: python

I'm want to create an app that can manage the volume of the pc, I found online "pycaw" and I tried to install it but when I run the command this is the result

```
 C:\Windows\system32>pip install pycaw
Collecting pycaw
  Using cached pycaw-20181226.tar.gz (5.7 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting comtypes
  Using cached comtypes-1.1.10.tar.gz (145 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting enum34
  Using cached enum34-1.1.10-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting psutil
  Using cached psutil-5.8.0.tar.gz (470 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting future
  Using cached future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pycaw, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for comtypes, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for future, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psutil, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psutil, future, enum34, comtypes, pycaw
    Running setup.py install for psutil ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s9ybt31o\\psutil_59ec22fef2094e26b1d24300f2b42416\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s9ybt31o\\psutil_59ec22fef2094e26b1d24300f2b42416\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h6emejwp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil'
         cwd: C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s9ybt31o\psutil_59ec22fef2094e26b1d24300f2b42416\
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psaix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psbsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pslinux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psosx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_psposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pssunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\_pswindows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    copying psutil\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_aix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_bsd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_contracts.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_linux.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_memleaks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_misc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_osx.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_sunos.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_system.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_testutils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\test_windows.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    copying psutil\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\psutil\tests
    running build_ext
    building 'psutil._psutil_windows' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s9ybt31o\\psutil_59ec22fef2094e26b1d24300f2b42416\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kevin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s9ybt31o\\psutil_59ec22fef2094e26b1d24300f2b42416\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', ope`n)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h6emejwp\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\psutil' Check the logs for full command output.`
```

I tried to uninstall python and reinstalling it, what should I do?
I should have all installed like visual studio build tools like I saw on another post

Comment: It explicitly tells you to install c++ build tools `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/`, what's the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is telling you how to solve it:

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

So, just install C++ Build Tools from the [link it's telling you](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).

Comment: I installed it but was the wrong library, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need only to install a visual c++ libraries.

Try to download it from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-160
without build tools. Pick x64 if you had a 64-bit Windows OS or x86 for 32-bit Windows OS.

Comment: It needs the build tools, not the runtime.